# Javascript animation flickering when run multiple times

Tags: javascript

So this is my first attempt at playing with JS animations. I just modified a simple tutorial to create a border that fades out when you click an element. It works perfectly the first time but every subsequent click it flickers and acts strangely. I can't work out what the issue is.

```
function move(elem) {
  var left = 1
  function frame() {
    left = left - 0.1  // update parameters
    elem.style.border = '6px solid rgba(48, 28, 237, '+left+')';
    if (left == 0)  // check finish condition
      clearInterval(id)
  }
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100) // draw every 10ms
}
```

HTML:

```
<div onclick="move(this)" class="example_path"></div>
```

Codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqrwoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript count float number is inaccuracy,
for example:
console.log(0.1+0.2);
not 0.3,is  0.30000000000000004,
so...
"left = left - 0.1" forever not equal to "0"
should be
"if(left == 0)"
modification
"if(left <= 0)"
I`m sorry my English is not good,express dimness.

Answer (score 2):

Your interval is not clearing.  Try this (if) condition:

```
    if (left <= 0) { // check finish condition
      clearInterval(id)
      // alert("cleared")
    }
```

Comment: That works, I already accepted another answer posted at the same time, his was the same but explained why it wasn't clearing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  I should have explained that too.